# Nginx location block with regex won't match URL

Tags: nginx, regex, pattern-matching

This is my server block.

```
server {
        set $auth_header 'Bearer my_token';
        listen 80;

        server_name my.domain.com;

        location ~ "(/d\-solo/[a-zA-Z]{8,10}/.+\?.+)" {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/$1;
                proxy_set_header Authorization $auth_header;
        }

        location ~ "(/api/dashboards/uid/[a-zA-Z]{8,10})" {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/$1;
                proxy_set_header Authorization $auth_header;
        }

        location ~ /(.*) {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
                #NO MATTER WHAT I DO, REQUESTS GO HERE
                proxy_set_header Authorization $auth_header;
        }
}
```

I've been unable to make my location blocks match urls. The url below, e.g., matches the lowermost block, but I would expect it to match the uppermost block.

`http://my.domain.com/d-solo/VYbRWmhZk/grafer?orgId=1&refresh=5m&from=1571353874733&to=1573949474733&var-Marketplace=&panelId=14`

Comment: How are you testing/confirming that it's going to the last location instead of the first?

Comment: Deleting the last block gives me a 404 with the URL I posted.

Comment: Location match uri without query parameters.

Comment: @AlexeyTen of course. I don't understand how or why I can spend three hours without realizing it. Paste your comment into an answer, and I will mark as accepted.